# Kubernetes RBAC rules for PersistentVolume

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I'm trying to create *RBAC Role / rules* for a service that needs a persistent volume and it's still failing with *forbidden* error.

Here is my role config:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: logdrop-user-full-access
  namespace: logdrop
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps", "autoscaling"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources:
  - jobs
  - cronjobs
  verbs: ["*"]
```

And this is my cut down *PersistentVolume* manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: logdrop-pv
  namespace: logdrop
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  claimRef:
    namespace: logdrop
    name: logdrop-pvc
  hostPath:
    path: /efs/logdrop/logdrop-pv
```

When I try to apply it I get a forbidden error.

```
$ kubectl --kubeconfig ~/logdrop/kubeconfig-logdrop.yml apply -f pv-test.yml 
Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "/v1, Resource=persistentvolumes", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=PersistentVolume"
Name: "logdrop-pv", Namespace: ""
Object: &{map["apiVersion":"v1" "kind":"PersistentVolume" "metadata":map["annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""] "name":"logdrop-pv"] "spec":map["accessModes":["ReadWriteMany"] "capacity":map["storage":"10Gi"] "claimRef":map["name":"logdrop-pvc" "namespace":"logdrop"] "hostPath":map["path":"/efs/logdrop/logdrop-pv"] "persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Retain"]]}
from server for: "pv-test.yml": persistentvolumes "logdrop-pv" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:logdrop:logdrop-user" cannot get resource "persistentvolumes" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

On the last line it specifically says `resource "persistentvolumes" in API group ""` - that's what I have allowed in the *rules*!

I can create the PV with *admin* credentials from the same yaml file and I can create any other resources (pods, services, etc) with the *logdrop* permissions. Just the *PersistentVolume* doesn't work for some reason. Any idea why?

I'm using Kubernetes 1.15.0.

Update:

This is my role binding as requested:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: logdrop-user-view
  namespace: logdrop
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: logdrop-user
  namespace: logdrop
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: logdrop-user-full-access
```

It's not a ClusterRoleBinding as my intention is to give the user access only to one namespace (`logdrop`), not to all namespaces across the cluster.

Answer (score 16):

PVs, namespaces, nodes and storages are **cluster-scoped** objects. As a best practice, to be able to list/watch those objects, you need to create *ClusterRole* and bind them to a *ServiceAccount* via *ClusterRoleBinding*. As an example;

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: <name of your cluster role>
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - nodes
  - persistentvolumes
  - namespaces
  verbs: ["list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: ["storage.k8s.io"]
  resources:
  - storageclasses
  verbs: ["list", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: <name of your cluster role binding>
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: <name of your cluster role which should be matched with the previous one>
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: <service account name>
```

Answer (score 9):

I see a potential problem here.

PersistentVolumes are `cluster scoped resources`. They are expected to be provisioned by the administrator without any namespace.

PersistentVolumeClaims however, can be created by users within a particular namespace as they are a `namespaced resources`.

That's why when you use `admin` credentials it works but with `logdrop` it returns an error.

Please let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score -2):

The new role needs to be granted to a user, or group of users, with a [rolebinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding), e.g.:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1 
kind: RoleBinding 
metadata: 
  name: logdrop-rolebinding
  namespace: logdrop 
subjects: 
- kind: User
  name: logdrop-user     
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io 
roleRef: 
  kind: Role
  name: logdrop-user-full-access 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: Thanks but I do have RoleBinding of course. I can use the role to create deployments, pods, services, even PersistentVolumeClaims! Just not *PersistentVolumes* :(

Comment: I see. Can you add your role binding to the question? I think the problem is that you need to use a cluster role and a cluster role binding in this case as PersistentVolumes are cluster-level resources.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the RoleBinding statement to the question. It is indeed a `RoleBinding`, not `ClusterRoleBinding` as I want to give the user unlimited access only to its namespace (`logdrop`) and not anywhere else.